# DStream all identical keys should be processed sequentially

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have dstream of (Key,Value) type.

```
mapped2.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  rdd.foreachPartition(p => {
    p.foreach(x => {
    }
  )})
})
```

I need to get assured that all items with identical keys are processed in one partition and by one core..so actually there are processed sequentially..

How to do this? Can I use GroupBykey which is inefficient?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PairDStreamFunctions.combineByKey`:

```
import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
/**
  * Created by Yuval.Itzchakov on 29/11/2016.
  */
object GroupingDStream {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val pairs: DStream[(String, String)] = ???
    val numberOfPartitions: Int = ???

    val groupedByIds: DStream[(String, List[String])] = pairs.combineByKey[List[String]](
      _ => List[String](), 
      (strings: List[String], s: String) => s +: strings, 
      (first: List[String], second: List[String]) => first ++ second, new HashPartitioner(numberOfPartitions))

    groupedByIds.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      rdd.foreach((kvp: (String, List[String])) => {

      })
    })
  }
}
```

The result of `combineByKey` would be a tuple with the first element being the key and the second element being a collection of the values. Note I used `(String, String)` for the sake of the simplicity of the example, as you haven't provided any types.

Then, using `foreach` to iterate the list of values and process them sequentially if you need. Note that if you need to apply additional transformations, you can use `DStream.map` and operate on the second element (list of values) instead of using `foreachRDD`.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your answer..Can I use another function such as partionbykey (to avoid inefficient grouping of key values pairs)..then does the my above code can guarantee values are executed serially (i.e,  on one core per executor)? or it should be by grouping. i.e,  accessed by values from a key value pair?

Comment: @mahdi62 why do you think combineByKey is inefficienct? It will locally combine all similar keys inside an executor and only shuffle the combined result over the wire.

Comment: The code actually gives empty lists for key, value pairs with one item...I guess the combiner should be     (x:String) =>List[String](x),