# RDD Identical keys should be processed sequentially

Tags: spark-streaming

I have a Dstream (K,V). My usecase necessitates that to process all tuples with identical keys sequentially. The process is like bellow:

```
val filestream=//..
fileStream.foreachRDD(r=>
{
    r.foreachparttion(p=>
   {

 p.foreach(x=>
{
 //x get the sate from Hbase
 //updates Hbase state for the key=k using the v and the retrieved state
})})})
```

Since for each tuple  and the corresponding key, I have states in HBase, so I need to be get assured all tuples with identical keys are process in one partition by one CPU core at each time, so each tuple get a valid states (not the stale and invalid one)..the concurrency of streaming application is 1 then.

Now I wanted to know if the above code is sufficient for my above requirement or Do I need to group key value further (for example, by using combinebykey [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032619/dstream-all-identical-keys-should-be-proccessed-sequentially))?

I wanted to know if accessing each tuple in RDDs in each partition (for each batch interval-as bellow)

```
p.foreach(x=>
{
 //x get the sate from Hbase
 //updates Hbase state for the key=k using the v and the retrieved state
})
```

would be sequential or it can be parallel as well?

Comment: What is the source of the stream? What needs to happen to identical keys?

Answer (score 1):

In general, in Spark Streaming, there're no warranties about which key lands in which receiver. Particular receiver implementations might offer that warranty or the possibility to implement it. 
For example, a Kafka consumer will give you the warranty that all data from one partition is consumed on one executor, so placing the same keys in the same partition will achieve the intended goal.

In the general case, to ensure that the same key is in the same Spark partition, we will need to repartition the data.  But to ensure that data from one key is processed sequentially, we will need to go one step further and put data for each key together. Combining these two steps can be done using `groupByKey`. Once we have the data in the form `key -> [data1, ..., datan]` we only need to request the current `(k,v)` from the db to complete the process.

In terms of code, we will have something like:

```
fileStream.foreachRDD{rdd =>
    val dataPerKey = rdd.map(entry => (key(entry),value(entry))).groupByKey()
    dataPerKey.forEachPartition{iter =>
        val dataMap = iter.toMap
        val keys = dataMap.keys
        // val dbState = HBase.get(keys)
        // val newData = process dataMap + dbState
        HBase.write(newData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks assuming that the above code guarantee all tuples with identical keys are executed on one thread

Comment: @mahdi62 the result of the code above is 1 key and a sequence of values for that key processed in one executor. This should provide enough guarantees of execution in a single context.